# Python detect which module a variable was first instantiated

Tags: python, import, introspection

How can I detect the module where a variable's value was first created? For example, consider these three files:

```py
# source1.py
class Test: pass
a = Test()
```

```py
# source2.py
import source1
b = source1.a
```

```py
# source3.py
import source2
c = source2.b

# What is the source module of variable "c"? Should return source1
```

In `source3.py`, how can I determine where the referenced object was declared?

The use case for this is some documentation generation code I'm writing, which does introspection on a python package.

Comment: Likely not a sensible question for primitive types like `int` or `str`, which would always be copied. But for functions, classes, and the like which will be referenced, seems like it should be possible.

Comment: Once you import module, you execute it.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for classes and non-anonymous functions, i.e. objects "declared" by the ``class`` or ``def`` statement? Are you looking in general for "a variable's value", including literals, displays, and general instantiation?

Comment: Yeah so looking for a variable's value, in general. Classes and functions will have `__module__` attribute, so I think that covers those. Primitives like `int`/`str` are not that important to me as I mentioned. Mainly I'm curious about class instances, is it possible to find what module they got instantiated in?

Comment: You cannot generally find out in which module an instance was created, and it generally is not meaningful either (e.g. with factory functions, alternate constructors, etc.).

Comment: That is unfortunate. Would have been nice to have a solution for normal class instantiation, but alas, I'll have to try to workaround it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you just need to check the global namespace of currently executing frame

Here is the code for the same

```
# source3.py
import source2
c = source2.b
import inspect
current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
print(current_frame.f_globals['c'])

output: <source1.Test object at 0x7f39058a0e50>
```

here you can see we have traced the reference of c

Comment: How does this answer the question? This does not find the first namespace given the object, it "finds" the object given the correct name and some namespace.

Comment: is it not answering the question `how can I determine where the referenced object was declared?`? you can see we got that it is declared in source1.

I thought i will be appreciated here. the owner has accepted the answer. I hope he got what he is looking for.

Comment: It's only saying where the class was defined - that the object happened to be defined there as well is purely coincidental; it won't work in general. Either way, if that is the desired result then there is no need to go through the hoops like that - simply `print(c)` has the same effect with much less assumptions.

Comment: Okay, but is he going to use print statement inside a documentation library he is writing?

Comment: Your code is using print, so formulating an equivalent does as well. The point is that `inspect.currentframe().f_globals['c']`  is equivalent to just `c`.